# Fourier basis of $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

I have read that the Hilbert space $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ has a Hilbert basis:
$$\{e^{inx}|n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$$
This to me indicates that we can only represent a function $u(x)$ by a Fourier Series iff $u(x)\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. However, I believe this is not a necessary condition and you may have a function $g(x)\notin L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ that can be represented by a Fourier series. To me this makes no sense since it means that:
$$g(x) \in span(e^{inx}|n\in\Bbb{Z})$$
But not in $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ which is also equal to  $span(e^{inx}|n\in\Bbb{Z})$. Please can someone explain this to me.

Comment: You are reasoning as if we were talking of a finite dimensional Hilbert space, but we are not. So you need to understand 1st what means "$u \in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ is represented as a Fourier series" : it means $\lim_{N \to \infty} \|u - S_N(u)\|_{L^2([-\pi,\pi])} \to 0$ where $S_N(u) = \sum_{n = -N}^N c_n e^{i n x}$. Note  how ***this is very different*** to the pointwise convergence

Comment: If $g \in C^1$ and is periodic, the pointwise convergence of its Fourier is ensured and everything is simple. But if $g \in L^1([-\pi,\pi])$ or $L^\infty([-\pi,\pi])$, or even worse if $g \in (C^1([-\pi,\pi]))^*$ (the dual of $C^1([-\pi,\pi])$, for example the  Dirac delta) then everything becomes much more complicated. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis

Comment: @user1952009 please can you explain the relevance of your first comment to my question. (i.e. can we use it to explain why the Fourier basis 'spans' the Hilbert space, but also other vectors)

Comment: the problem is $span((\phi_n))$, it doesn't have any simple meaning in infinite dimensional vector spaces. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series for getting an idea of this

Comment: and the answer to your question is that in infinite dimensional vector spaces, when you change the meaning of $span$, you change effectively the norm and the [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) that you are considering, adding or removing some elements